# $\sqrt[n]{ax^{n}+bx^{n-1}+...+c} ∼ \sqrt{a}|x+\frac{b}{na}| \ \ \ for:a>0 , n \in \mathbb{N} \ \ \text{even}$

Tags: limits

Written in my textbook that :

$$\sqrt[n]{ax^{n}+bx^{n-1}+...+c}_{x\to \infty} ∼ \sqrt{a}|x+\frac{b}{na}|  \ \ \ for:a>0 , n \in \mathbb{N} \ \ \text{even}$$
And :

$$\sqrt[n]{ax^{n}+bx^{n-1}+...+c} _{x\to \infty}∼ \sqrt{a}(x+\frac{b}{na})  \ \ \ for: , n \in \mathbb{N} \ \ \text{Odd number}$$

but I do not know why ? How to prove?please help me.

Comment: In effect, we have _three_ statements of quite different complexity; which of them you don't understand? Is it $\sqrt[n]a$, or the $|x|$ vs. simply $x$, or the $b\over na$ part?

Answer (score 2):

IMO you have typos, you should have $\sqrt[n]{a}$ on the RHS. Here I assume $a>0$ which is needed for even $n$ to get positive values in $ax^n$ for large $x$  and $b>0$ to get rid of the $|\dots|.$

$$\sqrt[n]{ax^{n}+bx^{n-1}+\dots+c}=(ax^{n}+bx^{n-1}+\dots+c)^{1/n}
=\left(ax^n\left(1+\frac{b}{a}\frac{1}{x}  +\dots+ \frac{c}{a}\frac{1}{x^n}\right)\right)^{1/n}
=\sqrt[n]{a}x\left(1+\frac{b}{a}\frac{1}{x}  +\dots+ \frac{c}{a}\frac{1}{x^n}\right)^{1/n}
$$
Now use the well-known asymptotic expression $(1+y)^r \sim 1 + r y$ for $y \rightarrow 0$ with $r=1/n$ and $y=1/x$ and $x\rightarrow \infty$

$$\sqrt[n]{ax^{n}+bx^{n-1}+\dots+c}
\sim \sqrt[n]{a}x\left(1+\frac{b}{na}\frac{1}{x}\right)
=\sqrt[n]{a}\left(x+\frac{b}{na}\right)
$$

I guess you can continue this basics for your cases.